# Process each item in a mysql "group by" individually before getting result?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to do this for a while, but I might be thinking completely wrong here.

I have a table called `songs` with `ID`, `Artist`, `play_count` and a table called info with `ID`, `length_seconds`.

I want to make a query that sums `length_seconds` * `play_count` for each individual track.

I wrote this query, which is wrong.

```
SELECT Artist
     , sum(play_count) AS total_plays
     , sum(play_count) * length_seconds as play_length
     , count(*) as count 
  FROM songs
     , info 
 WHERE songs.ID = info.ID 
 GROUP 
    BY artist 
 ORDER 
    BY total_plays DESC
```

This query only takes into account the length of the first track. So if the data is like this

```
ID Artist play_count
1 Artist 2
2 Artist 2

ID length_seconds
1 10
1 100
```

The output of my query will be

```
 Artist 4   40  2
```

While I want to it be

```
 Artist 4   220 2
```

How could I rewrite this query so that it takes into account the length of each track individually?

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992

Comment: @Strawberry You mean the formatting or the query itself? I find it cleaner to have the query on one line, if isn't complex. I've got no idea about 90s programming since I was born in 2002.

Comment: No, I meam using implicit JOIN syntax instead of proper joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Artist, sum(play_count) AS total_plays, sum(play_count * length_seconds) as play_length, count(*) as count FROM songs, info WHERE songs.ID = info.ID GROUP BY artist ORDER BY total_plays DESC
```

Comment: Oh wow, just one parenthesis moved. Thank you!